# Is it possible to pass parameters from react Route tag to Navigate tag?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

The contents are as follows.

```
<Route path="/:id" >
    <Navigate
      to="/intro?Id=:id"
    />
  </Route>
```

Is there a way to pass the :id parameter to the Route tag as the :id parameter to the Navigate tag like this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "pass the :id parameter to the Route tag as the :id parameter to the Navigate tag"? Which navigation package are you using, `react-router` or `react-navigation`? I doubt you are using both.

Comment: Once I use the Route and Navigate of react-router-dom.
And 
I approached it with /1234, which only resulted in '/intro?id=:id'. What I want is '/intro?id=1234'.

Comment: Are you using `react-router-dom` version 6? What is `Navigate`?

Comment: I see in package.json that "^6.0.0-beta.0" is being used, 
What is Navigate? is.. I don't know what that means, Navigate tag is defined in node_modules/react-router/index.d in my project package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I see, so you want to render essentially a redirect from "/:id" to "intro?Id=:id".

You can't just redirect from one path to the other since you are dynamically using the `id` route match param as part of a querystring parameter, and since  `react-router-dom` doesn't deal with the URL querystring you need to handle this mapping yourself. It took a bit of digging through the version 6 docs but this is what I've come up with:

1. Create a custom component to read the match param and render the `Navigate` component.

   ```
   const IntroRedirect = () => {
     const { id } = useParams();
     return <Navigate replace to={`/intro?Id=${id}`} /> 
   };
   ```
2. Render `MyNavigate` on a `Route`.

   ```
   <Route path="/:id" element={<IntroRedirect />} />
   ```

[image: Edit is-it-possible-to-pass-parameters-from-react-route-tag-to-navigate-tag]

Full demo code:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate,
  useLocation,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

const IntroRedirect = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return <Navigate replace to={`/intro?Id=${id}`} />;
};

const Intro = () => {
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const query = new URLSearchParams(search);
  const Id = query.get("Id");

  return <div>Intro: Id="{Id}"</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <Router>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/1234">"/1234"</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/4567">"/4567"</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/7890">"/7890"</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/intro" element={<Intro />} />
          <Route path="/:id" element={<IntroRedirect />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw the code that the teacher helped and applied and solved the problem. Thank you again.